# Can you hide in a Giant Frog's stomach?

Tags: dnd-5e, stealth

In D&D, it is possible to get a Giant Frog companion (as a Beast Master ranger). I was wondering what would happen if your companion swallowed you.

Would you take damage? Can you ride in its belly? If you do take damage, does it apply out of combat?

Could you use this to infiltrate a Bullywug base? And could you do this with a Druid when they Wild Shape into a beast?

I read a piece of Bullywug lore and am not sure if it’s official, but it said something about Bullywugs using Giant Frogs' Swallow to capture creatures.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) if you haven't already, and check out the [help center](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help) for more guidance.

Comment: Is your ranger of a small sized race?  (Halfling or Gnome?)

Answer (score 13):

## Sort of, you might not like this

Let's start at the top: can a [Giant Frog](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/giant-frog) swallow you? Well the Giant Frog's swallow ability says:

> The frog makes one bite attack against a Small or smaller target it is grappling. If the attack hits, the target is swallowed, [...]

So assuming you are Small (Halfling, Gnome, Goblin, Kobold; no Tiny PC options currently available) and are already grappled (which assuming you are willing and have time isn't a problem) it can swallow you. Now comes the bummer: in addition to being blinded and restrained, you take 2d4 acid at start of the frog's turn. No save, no option, just an average 5 damage per round. If you, nor your companions kill the frog, you will die. Congratulations, you just made yourself food for your own animal companion.

Rules-as-written the frog has no option to regurgitate a swallowed creature, though a reasonable DM might let it. So you may be able to infiltrate a bullywug base through this method, assuming you have a way to sustain 50 acid damage per minute<sup>1</sup> and the bullywug don't question a unknown giant frog knocking on their door.

Regarding any precedence for creature transport, the *Monster Manual* includes (page 35):

> The [giant] frogs' ability to swallow creatures whole provides a bullywug hunting band an easy means of carrying prey back to their villages.

This notably doesn't include the word "alive". So while it does imply the frogs can regurgitate swallowed creatures (otherwise the bullywugs would go through quite a number of them), it doesn't mean the prey lives. As for any acid damage to the swallowed prey, it is quite possible acid stained meat is a delicacy among the bullywug, it certainly no worse than some of the real-world human ones.

---

1: Most likely immunity if you can somehow pick it up. Resistance will half the damage, but 25 dpm is also going to be very limiting on your time/survivability.

Comment: "Hey pal, can i ride in your stomach so we can infiltrate this Bullywug base? Now remember, don't burn me!" :)

Comment: The Monster Manual entry for bullywugs does include the lore the OP mentions, albeit that: "The frogs’ ability to swallow creatures whole provides a bullywug hunting band an easy means of carrying prey back to their villages." Though bullywugs tend to capture intelligent trespassers alive so they can lord it over them, the use of frog-based transportation is likely meant to be for prey the hunting party has killed and will consume later.